# How to call a function without a "direct" click, since it has a stopPropagation for the Row Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this function working fine on its own. Ej. click

```
$('.ajax').on('click', function () {
        $modal.load('modal_ajax_test.html', '', function () {
            $modal.modal();
        });
});
```

But I need to call it from a button inside a Table>Row. The row has a click event listener to it. So,

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btnID'+25);
btn.addEventListener("click",function(ev){
ev.stopPropagation(); // stops propagation of row click.
console.log('btn clicked');
// call jQuery from here *
btnClicked();
```

Up to here this also works fine. The button only triggers itself, and not the row click.

So, now I have to call the jquery function from here *.

I tried:

```
$( ".ajax" ).trigger( "click" );
$('.ajax').click();
```

They work, but both trigger many instances of the call.

.bind didn't work:

```
$(".ajax").bind("click");
```

So, I'm trying to build this function:

```
function btnClicked(){
        $modal.load('modal_ajax_test.html', '', function () {
            $modal.modal();
        });
}
```

But console says "undefined". because it's inside 2 anonymous functions.

```
var UIModals = function () {
    //function to initiate bootstrap extended modals
    var initModals = function () {
        $.fn.modalmanager.defaults.resize = true;
        $.fn.modal.defaults.spinner = $.fn.modalmanager.defaults.spinner = ...

    function btnClicked(){
            $modal.load('modal_ajax_test.html', '', function () {
                $modal.modal();
            });
    }
```

if I move it out is defined, but the new function is missing the main variables $modal ...

How can I call the function?

EDITED:

By the way, if I remove the row click event, the modal works fine with all 3 methods: .trigger, .click, & triggerhandler

```
rowTr.onclick=function(){
google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i],'click');
```

...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, I just don't know how, but all of a sudden works.

works fine with all 3 methods: .trigger, .click, & triggerhandler

it doesn't work with .bind